# open popup in alreadily open pop up window

Tags: javascript, jsp

My jsp application has one home page and that has so many anchors `<a>` for accessing different pages using AJAX.
one anchor is for creating user which opens a particular user registration window using javascript `window.open` of size `1050*600`.

at end of use r registration i am providing two anchors :
1. for displaying preview of registered info and 
2. for taking print out of registered info.

both are of size `500*200` and again I am calling javscript `window.open()` to open these two windows.
but it's not they are taking same size as that of parent pop up (ie.1050*600).

how to open pop-up in alreadily open pop-up window?

Answer (score 0):

where do you have print preview ? in the register page itself ? if yes then you can use window.resizeTo in your print preview page to reset to the size you want, ideally its

`window.resizeTo(500,200);` in your case